# How can I select multiple items that are generated in real time with JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the user preferences, which will be 5 or 10, I haven't defined that yet.

But the options that will be shown in the first instance are the following (They are being retrieved in a JSON through a WebApi, but for example, I put what I get):

```
<?php
    $json2 = '{"0":{"Id_Categoria":2,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725779\/neb2ymglgqmmaexgkcez.png","Nombre":"Vinos y licores","Activo":1,"demanda":148},"1":{"Id_Categoria":1,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725152\/umk40bjvcxpoc08bcu7q.png","Nombre":"Calzado","Activo":1,"demanda":52},"2":{"Id_Categoria":21,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Carnicerias","Activo":1,"demanda":9},"3":{"Id_Categoria":22,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Cafeterias","Activo":1,"demanda":7},"4":{"Id_Categoria":25,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Taquerias","Activo":1,"demanda":7},"5":{"Id_Categoria":3,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725966\/q5cczltjedz1wg1iat8f.jpg","Nombre":"Articulos (c\u00f3mputo)","Activo":1,"demanda":6},"6":{"Id_Categoria":24,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Tintorerias","Activo":1,"demanda":6},"7":{"Id_Categoria":4,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Paletass y helados","Activo":1,"demanda":5},"8":{"Id_Categoria":5,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726157\/qad9inm54ma56s2s4tta.png","Nombre":"Comercios de Pintura","Activo":1,"demanda":5},"9":{"Id_Categoria":23,"Imagen":"https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png","Nombre":"Ferreterias","Activo":1,"demanda":4}}';
    
    echo($json2);
?>
```

I am retrieving this JSON with ajax in the following way (I think it is the simplest):

```
$("#Abrir").click(function() {
        //$(document).ready(function(){
        //invocar json desde jquery
        $("#Class2 div").remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "prueba.php",
            //Datos que se envian a prueba.php
            data: {},
            //Cambiar a type: POST si necesario
            type: "GET",
            // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(datos) {
                //Información que llega
                var salida = "";
                $.each(datos, function(i, val) {
                    salida += "<div class='box Ide_Cat box" + val.Id_Categoria + "' id=" + val
                        .Id_Categoria + ">";
                    salida += "<img src='" + val.Imagen + "' alt = '" + val.Id_Categoria +
                        "'>";
                    salida += "<h2 id='Nom'>" + val.Nombre + "</h2>";
                    salida += "<input type='hidden' Id ='Id_cat'value='" + val
                        .Id_Categoria + "'>";
                    salida += "</div>";
                });
                $("#Class2").append(salida);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log("La solicitud a fallado: " + error);
                console.log("La solicitud a fallado: " + jqXHR);
                console.log("La solicitud a fallado: " + status);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
                //alert("Transaccion completa");
            }
        });
    });
```

and they're getting in here:

```
<div class="container-box " id="Class2">
  <div id="box" class="box">
    <input type="hidden" value="12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class=" row justify-content-center">
  <a href="#" id="a-submit">Enviar selecciones</a>
</div>
```

To get multiple selections of categories (because that's what I think would work) displayed I have found several solutions but they don't work as I think I require, because the following: on a click event it does not retrieve the Id of the category the user is selecting but retrieves the Id_ of the first category only, regardless of whether the last one was selected:

```
var imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('#Class2');
    var titular = document.querySelector('#Id_cat');
    var Id_cts = new Array();
    $("#Abrir").ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
            imagenes[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                var ide = ('#Id_cat').val();
                var nombre = $('#Nom').val();
                console.log("El id de la categoria seleccionada es: "+ ide + " y el nombre es: " + nombre)
                var texto = "nombre";
            });       
        }
    });
```

And the following code only works by pressing the CTRL button although it still only retrieves the id_category of the first category regardless if you select the last one:

```
var selected_rows = []
    $("#Class2").click(function() {
        let clicked_row = $(this)
        if (clicked_row.hasClass('selected')) {
            clicked_row.removeClass('selected')
        } else {
            clicked_row.addClass('selected')
        }
    });

    $('#a-submit').click(function() {
        data = []
        selections = $('.selected')
        selections.each((index, element) => {
            let row_content = {
                Id_cat: $(element).find('#Id_cat').val(),
                lastname: $(element).find('#Nom').text(),
            }
            data.push(row_content)
        })
        console.log("Your selections:", data)
    })
```

In a nutshell:

Based on the JSON categories.

1-. I want to get the user's preferences

2.- There must be at least 5 or more categories selected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You state, *There must be at least 5 or more categories selected.* How is the User going to "select" these? By checkbox? Clicking on them? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I want the "box" containers to be selected.
as shown in the following link:
https://magtimus.github.io/proyectos/Cajas-seleccionables-con-efecto-hover/index.html

In this example, only one option is selected at a time, and in my case, I will not use the checkboxes because they take away the presentation of the application.

Comment: The answer I posted will lead you to that. Users will be able to Click and un-click the item they want to select in a similar fashion. The rest is all Styling.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
var myData = [{
    "Id_Categoria": 2,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725779\/neb2ymglgqmmaexgkcez.png",
    "Nombre": "Vinos y licores",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 148
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 1,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725152\/umk40bjvcxpoc08bcu7q.png",
    "Nombre": "Calzado",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 52
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 21,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Carnicerias",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 9
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 22,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Cafeterias",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 7
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 25,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Taquerias",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 7
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 3,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631725966\/q5cczltjedz1wg1iat8f.jpg",
    "Nombre": "Articulos (c\u00f3mputo)",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 6
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 24,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Tintorerias",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 6
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 4,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Paletass y helados",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 5
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 5,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726157\/qad9inm54ma56s2s4tta.png",
    "Nombre": "Comercios de Pintura",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 5
  },
  {
    "Id_Categoria": 23,
    "Imagen": "https:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dcksq4ylu\/image\/upload\/v1631726499\/ciperp26mazrm7wao9fs.png",
    "Nombre": "Ferreterias",
    "Activo": 1,
    "demanda": 4
  }
];

$(function() {
  function makeSalidas(data, target) {
    var cid = data.Id_Categoria;
    var salidas = $("<div>", {
      class: "box Ide_Cat box-" + cid,
      id: "box-" + cid,
    }).data("box", data);
    $("<img>", {
      src: data.Imagen,
      alt: "Box " + cid
    }).appendTo(salidas);
    $("<h2>", {
      id: "nom-" + cid
    }).html(data.Nombre).appendTo(salidas);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "hidden",
      id: "Id_cat-" + cid
    }).appendTo(salidas);
    if (target == undefined) {
      return salidas;
    } else {
      salidas.appendTo(target);
    }
  }

  $("#Class2").empty();
  $.each(myData, function(i, v) {
    makeSalidas(v, "#Class2");
  });

  $("#Class2").on("click", ".box", function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });

  $("#a-submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selected = [];
    $(".box.selected").each(function(i, el) {
      selected.push($(el).data("box").Id_Categoria);
    });
    console.log(selected);
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 270px;
  height: 280px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.box.selected {
  border-color: red;
}

.box.selected h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 15px;
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-box" id="Class2">
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <a href="#" id="a-submit">Enviar selecciones</a>
</div>
```

With a simple function, we can use a single items Data and make all the HTML elements we want. Remember that IDs in HTML must be unique.

Using `.data()`, we can store the Data for each with the Box for easy reference later.

We can use `.toggleClass()` to add/remove a class when the user wants to select a specific item. We can then use that same Class name to help identify which items were selected when we submit the data.

When submitted, I setup an array and entered the Category IDs into the array so that it can more easily be posted to an API or worked with in a Database.

Your script will be more like the following.

```
$("#Abrir").click(function(event) {
  $.getJSON("prueba.php", function(datos){
    $("#Class2").empty();
    $.each(datos, function(i, v) {
      makeSalidas(v, "#Class2");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Great, it's much more than I needed. Thank you very much for the help.
Just one more question:
$ .getJSON ("test.php", function (data) {

this part replaces the ajax or how does this line work?

Comment: @DesarrolladorNoob yes, this would replace the AJAX that you have. It's a short-hand version to GET JSON data, but behind the scenes it's the exact same.

Comment: @DesarrolladorNoob I updated the styling after seeing the example you provided. It's not exactly the same, yet it is similar enough that it should help.